# Calling dispose function in stateless widget using provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I maintain a state of a counter(let say) in a separate Singelton class I am using provider in my app and I want to reset that state when I pop the current screen widget will it be possible.

Note: I want to use the stateless widget as in stateful its possible but any idea about achieving this in stateless.Like some sort of dispose function in changeNotifier provider.

Comment: any class extended with `ChangeNotifier` gets an Dispose function you can override.

Comment: Can you please show a code snippet.

Comment: posted an answer with example code, please mark as answer and upvote if it helped you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any class extended with `ChangeNotifier` gets an Dispose function you can override.

**Example:**

```
class MyClass with ChangeNotifier {
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // dispose your stuff here
        super.dispose();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ChangeNotifierProvider()` and `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` is different.
`ChangeNotifierProvider()` will set `dispose` method by default, but `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` won't.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider({
    Key? key,
    required Create<T> create,
    bool? lazy,
    TransitionBuilder? builder,
    Widget? child,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          create: create,
          dispose: _dispose,
          lazy: lazy,
          builder: builder,
          child: child,
        );
```

Comment: Thanks! You have finalized my problem with this comment.